# pydevd_resolver.py:138: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="? if found.get(name) is not 1:

Tags: pycharm

new to python and using Pycharm 2019.1.3 professional and Python 3.8.0
get the following error when I open Python Console
does anyone know how to fix this?

```
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py" --mode=client --port=55208
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_resolver.py:138: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
  if found.get(name) is not 1:
```

Comment: Please do not post links to images of errors. Paste the entire error as text instead.

Answer (score 15):

What you posted is a new warning implemented in Python 3.8. Read [this](https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/01/21/why-does-python-3-8-syntaxwarning-for-is-literal/) article for more details. The warning itself is not why Python Console doesn't work.

The reason is at the bottom: `TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)`.

I think your version of PyCharm may simply not support Python 3.8. According to [this](https://jaxenter.com/jetbrains-pycharm-2019-3-165227.html) you need at least version 2019.3.

Comment: I could have sworn the python linters used to complain if you **didn't** use `is not` because != is "not pythonic"

Comment: @SurpriseDog Right? Because it avoided a dereference lookup! At least we're going back to sense.